# Chipping the ends of rectangle to make them spear-like

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I would like to chip/modify the ends of a rectangle element using `d3.js` so that they look like spears (imagine one of its end look like a triangle). Currently, I am achieving this effect by appending a `triangle-up` symbol rotated suitably, and appended to the end of rectangle. I searched for other solutions but failed to find one.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: You could create a custom path generator that gives you the shape you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can using a path to generate your triangles or pointy bits.

```
var lineData = [ { "x": 50,   "y": 150},// Left pointy bit
             { "x": 100,  "y": 100},// top left
             { "x": 300,  "y": 100},// top right
             { "x": 350,  "y": 150},// right pointy bit
             { "x": 300,  "y": 200},// bottom right
             { "x": 100,  "y": 200},// bottom left
             { "x": 50,   "y": 150}];// Back to left pointy bit

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return d.x; })
.y(function(d) { return d.y; })
.interpolate("linear");

d3.select("svg")
.append("path")
.attr("stroke", "#333")
.attr("stroke-width", 1.2)
.attr("opacity", 0.5)
.attr("fill", "CadetBlue")
.attr("d", lineFunction(lineData));
```

Here is an example on js fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dyna8/